# Matplotlib animation of the values of a 3D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, 3d, refresh

I am currently want to visualize 3D-rawdata out of my Walabot device and display it in a 3D animation created with matplotlib FuncAnimation. I already searched for answers, but I could not find anything helpful.
In my case I already have a 3 dimensional array, where each index has a specific value, which changes over the time. I already could figure out how to display it in a 3D chart with different colors and sizes but now I want to make update itself. I have found some example code which gave me a good start, but my chart does not update on its own. I have to close the window and then the window pops up again with different values from the 3D array. Do you guys know how to solve this problem? 
Here is my code so far:

```
def update(plot, signal, figure):
    plot.clear()
    scatterplot = plot.scatter(x, y, z, zdir='z', s=signal[0], c=signal[0])
    figure.show()
    return figure

def calc_RasterImage(signal):
    # 3D index is represnted is the following schema {i,j,k}
    #  sizeX - signal[1] represents the i dimension length
    #  sizeY - signal[2] represents the j dimension length
    #  sizeZ - signal[3] represents the k dimension length
    #  signal[0][i][j][k] - represents the walabot 3D scanned image (internal data)

    #Initialize 3Dplot with matplotlib                      
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.set_xlim([xMin-1,xMax-1])
    ax.set_ylim([yMin-1,yMax-1])
    ax.set_zlim([zMin-1,zMax-1])
    ax.set_xlabel('X AXIS')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y AXIS')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z AXIS')
    scatterplot = ax.scatter(x, y, z, zdir='z', s=signal[0], c= signal[0])
    cbar = plt.colorbar(scatterplot)
    cbar.set_label('Density')
    #def update(signal):
    #        ax.clear()
    #       scatterplot = ax.scatter(x, y, z, zdir='z', s=signal[0], c=signal[0])
    ani = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, update(ax, signal, plt), frames=10 , blit=True, repeat = True)

def main():
    wlbt = Walabot()
    wlbt.connect()
    if not wlbt.isConnected:
            print("Not Connected")
    else:
            print("Connected")
    wlbt.start()
    calc_index(wlbt.get_RawImage_values())
    while True:
            #print_RawImage_values(wlbt.get_RawImage_values())
            calc_RasterImage(wlbt.get_RawImage_values())
    wlbt.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see the row with

```
ani = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, update(ax, signal, plt), frames=10 , blit=True, repeat = True)
```

needs the update function from the top. This function clears my plot and recreates a new plot with different values. But I always need to close the plot window first, which I would like to avoid.
This is how the plot looks like:
[3D array plot with matplotlib scatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAIsg.png)
Do you guys have an idea how to solve this problem?

cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code isn't really a minimal working example, and you shouldn't be lazy and actually read the docs for FuncAnimation before coming to SO. That being said, something like this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Display walabot output.
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def display(walabot_instance):

    # set x, y, z

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    path_collection = ax.scatter(x, y, z, zdir='z')

    # do your labelling, layout etc

    def update(ignored, walabot_instance):
        signal = walabot_instance.get_RawImage_values()
        path_collection.set_sizes(signal[0])
        path_collection.set_color(signal[1])
        return path_collection,

    return FuncAnimation(fig, update, fargs=[walabot_instance])

def main():
    wlbt = Walabot()
    wlbt.connect()
    if not wlbt.isConnected:
        print("Not Connected")
    else:
        print("Connected")
    wlbt.start()

    plt.ion()
    animation = display(wlbt)
    raw_input("Press any key when done watching Walabot...")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you have any questions (after having read the docs!), drop a comment.

Comment: It seems a bit contradictory to criticize the missing mcve and still provide an answer, which itself does not have any explanation in it. I guess reminding the questioner of the missing clearness of the question should be a comment; on the other hand if you are able to answer the question, why bother about the mcve missing? Or the other way around: Why providing an answer if the question is unclear? In any case, throwing in a piece of code and then say "If you want to understand it, read the docs" is equally bad.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I asked him to read the docs _first_ and then ask any remaining questions. I would argue that there is a difference between what I actually said and how you are portraying it.